# Azure Blob Storage: Filter Event Subscription for the BlobCreated Event by Container Name

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure storage account with a blob storage which hosts multiple containers. So far, I've successfully created an event which listens to the `Microsoft.Storage.BlobCreated` event and calls a webhook inside my Web API project.

When the event is being processed in the Web API, we would like to know into which container the file was uploaded to. The current [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage#list-of-the-events-for-azure-data-lake-storage-gen-2-rest-apis) does not support this information.

Our intended workaround will be to append the container name into the file name and parse it in the Web API and start the processing logic based on the container name. Is there a better way to append the container name to the BlobCreated Event data?

There seems to be an issue about this on [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/779) with no official solution. I'm hoping that there already is a better workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now no SDK to get the container trigger. There are some existing issues about function or other services. For now no direct way to implement this.

However from the [event response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-blob-storage#microsoftstorageblobcreated-event), you could find the subject contains the container details, so you could just use `split()` method to get it.

For testing purposes, I use the logic app with js. The subject is the `subject` in the event json data. The split with `/` and get the container name in the array. In the actual situations, after the container name is the virtual path and suppose this is not what you want so just get the index 4 value is the container name.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh, you are right. The container name is indeed included in the path  I can extract it from there. Thank you!